# How to use a specified Hive database when using Sqoop import

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://remote-ip/db --username xxx --password xxx --table tb --hive-import
```

The above command imports table *tb* into the '`default`' Hive database.

Can I use other database instead?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Off the top of my head i recall you can specify `--hive-table foo.tb`

where foo is your hive database and tb is your hive table.

so in your case it would be:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://remote-ip/db --username xxx --password xxx --table tb --hive-import --hive-table foo.tb
```

As a footnote, here is the original jira issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-322

Answer (score 10):

**Hive database using Sqoop import:**

`sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/arun  --table account --username root --password root -m 1  --hive-import **--hive-database** company **--create-hive-table --hive-table** account  --target-dir /tmp/customer/ac`

Comment: strange: `--hive-database` seems to be an undocumented option [http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html] but it works for me as exactly expected. My sqoop-version on cloudera returns: `INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6-cdh5.13.0 Sqoop 1.4.6-cdh5.13.0`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. As in certain cases, we need to specify the database name.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the database name as a part of the `--hive-table` parameter, e.g. "`--hive-table foo.tb`".

There is a new request to add a special parameter for the database that is being tracked: [SQOOP-912](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-912).